# how to use flash player to show a live stream tv in my html site

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I need a help please

I have live stream link ,, which is in a private network ,, whatever.. 
here is my live tv link : "http://172.16.1.10:2188"
I need to embed the live tv link in my html codes using application/x-shockwave-flash ... 
its already done using application/x-vlc-plugin" ,, 
and it's work with this code , without any problem :

```
<embed style="width:100%; height:inherit;" type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" id="vlc" target="http://172.16.1.10:2188" <="" embed="" height="327" width="705">
```

but now I need it to work with flash player , not vlc player 
and dont know what the exact code to use .

here are some codes I tried , but still doesn't work : 
1>>

```
<embed style="width:100%; height:inherit;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"  id="vlc" target="http://172.16.1.10:2188" <="" embed="" height="327" width="705">
```

2>>

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
 <source src="http://172.16.1.10:2188" type='application/x-shockwave-flash' />
</video>
```

3>>

```
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" target="http://172.16.1.10:2188" data="http://172.16.1.10:2188"  width="780" height="420">

   </object>

  </object>
```